# How to default markdown-mode's markdown-live-preview-mode to vertical split

Tags: window, window-splitting, markdown-mode

Using [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/), I can run `M-x markdown-live-preview-mode` (or `C-c C-c l`) and it will split the window horizontally and display the rendered markdown (i.e. the HTML) with `eww` in a window below the markdown text window. How can I get this command to instead split the window vertically so that the markdown and rendered output are side by side? I'd like to avoid having to manually [toggle the window split](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [Window Choice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html#Window-Choice) in the emacs documentation, I was able to get the desired behaviour by setting `split-height-threshold` to `nil`. I added this to my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
```

Comment: Hmm I did this but nothing happened. Was there something else you had to add to your .emacs file? Was this the only line?